# Magento 2 CRUD Models: Create and Update Time

Tags: magento2, php, orm

I've created a Magento 2 CRUD/Abstract model that updates the following MySQL table.

```
CREATE TABLE `pulsestorm_commercebug_log` (
  `pulsestorm_commercebug_log_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `json_log` mediumtext NOT NULL COMMENT 'Demo Title',
  `creation_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Creation Time',
  `update_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Modification Time',
  `is_active` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Is Active',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pulsestorm_commercebug_log_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='pulsestorm_commercebug_log';
```

I can successfully use the model's `save` method to add data to this table.  However, the `creation_time` and `update_time` columns are **not** updated.  Their initial values are `NULL`.

Do I need to do something special with my models to get these creation and update times columns working?  Does anyone that's run into similar problems know of a solution?

If not -- does anyone know where in Magento 2's code base the ORM normally populate these values? (so I can debug what's wrong with my Models there)

Comment: Why are you do not use  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value and on update?

Comment: @KAndy SQL create came from copying something in core (can't remember what).  Are you saying that the create/update functionality relies on CURRENT_TIMESTAMP being set for the default value and update value?  i.e. its not something manager on the ORM level?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out (thanks [KAndy](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/12503/kandy)!) that the creation and update timestamps are **not** handled on the ORM level.  If you want this functionality, you need to make sure your database tables are created with the correct timestamp attributes.  i.e., in your install schema, something like.

```
    )->addColumn(
        'creation_time',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
        null,
        ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
        'Creation Time'
    )->addColumn(
        'update_time',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
        null,
        ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE],
        'Modification Time'
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

There is another example of how to achieve this inside the wishlist module. Look in the beforeSave() method on Model/Wishlist.php. Here is the code snippet

```
/**
 * Set date of last update for wishlist
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function beforeSave()
{
    parent::beforeSave();
    $this->setUpdatedAt($this->_date->gmtDate());
    return $this;
}
```